# Javascript - Array length returns 0 but elements are exist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I am getting data from firestore and then pushing data to array which returns an empty array. But items are exist

```
let viewData = []


 firestore.collection('views').where('viewid', '==', props.user.uid).orderBy('viewat', 'desc').limit(6).get().then(views => {
   if (views.empty === false) {
      views.forEach(item => {
         firestore.collection('userdata').doc(item.data().myid).get().then( user=> {
            viewData.push(user.data())
        })
        // +++ Working fine here +++
        // viewData.push(item.data())
    })
  }
  console.log(viewData)
})
```

Above code prints an empty array in the console. But elements are exist inside the array. When we try to push **item.data()** is working fine. At the same time Array.push is not working for the **user.data()**. I am not sure why Array.push behaves in this manner.

Comment: you are mixing async and sync calls. your `console.log` will be printed **before** every promise is resolved

Comment: How can i resolve this?.

Comment: try to understand the duplicate link marked by @adiga